# Getting OpenStack Container Metadata

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds

im using jclouds SDK, to handle OpenStack resources using Java, yet i couldn't anyway to get the metadata of the Container, in the `ContainerApi` class there is `updateMetadata` but i couldn't find any function to get the meta, also i didn't find any solution in the examples, so is there anyway to get the metadata?
also i looked over the internet if there is any example that utilizes how to use jclouds Java dependencies to achieve this task but didn't find any

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ContainerApi.get` returns a `Container` which you can then get user metadata via `getMetadata`.